# Frechet derivative and Lagrangian

Tags: calculus-of-variations, frechet-derivative

Consider the Lagrangian $L:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x,y,z\rightarrow L(x,y,z)$ and cost functional defined by the integral of a lagrangian
$$J(y) := \int_{a}^bL(x,y(x),y'(x))dx$$
I would like to prove that the first variation obtained by the Gateaux derivative
$$\delta J|_y(\eta)=\int_a^bL_y(x,y(x),y'(x))\eta(x) + L_z(x,y(x),y'(x))\eta'(x)dx$$
is also the first variation for the Frechet derivative, which is defined as
$$J(y+\eta):=J(y) + \delta J|_y(\eta) + o(||\eta||)$$
for the 1-norm on the space of continuously differentiable functions
$$||\eta||:= \max_{a\leq x\leq b}|\eta(x)| + \max_{a\leq x\leq b}|\eta'(x)|$$.

Basically, I'd like some help with proving
$$\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}\frac{||\int_{a}^bL(x,y+\eta,y'+\eta') - L(x,y,y')-L_y(x,y,y')\eta + L_z(x,y,y')\eta'dx||}{||\eta||} = 0$$
possibly using only the definitions above. I'm new to calculus of variations and I'm not sure on how to expand the part coming from $J(y+\eta)$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: same as here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583024/show-that-the-lagrangian-int-i-ht-ct-c-primet-dt-is-frechet-differenti/

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. What puzzles me about that solution is that the answer seems to use the usual definition of differentiability, i.e. treating the increments $h_1,h_2$ as scalars (or as in that case, elements of a finite dimensional space $X$). In my context is like saying that the Frechet derivative of $L$ is exactly the integrand of $\delta J|_{y}(\eta)$, which is what I want to prove. But $\eta$ is not an element of a finite dimensional space, it's a an element of the infinite dimensional space of $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions. What am i missing?

Comment: In the first part of the answer $h_1$, $h_2$ are scalars indeed, and then $\eta$ is just plugged in there in the equation for the standard derivative of $H$.

Comment: The main trick is to prove that the integral of the remainder ($g$) of the derivative of $H$ also converges to zero.

Comment: But if one can treat $\eta$ equivalently to a scalar, why would we need to define the first variation in the first place. In fact, there would be no need to define the first variation of a functional as different from the 'common' derivative of a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I understand the rest of the proof; what I don't get is how to justify the expansion of $H$ since the increment is a function rather than a scalar.

Comment: You expand $H$ normally and then plug functions into the increments because the functions has the range of real values.

Comment: You need to treat it differently because you have different notion of convergence in this case.